# Unable to automate testing of Unity apps using AltUnity Tester for IOS Simulator builds

Tags: python, selenium, unity-game-engine, automation, ios-simulator

I've successfully executed automated testing scripts in Python for my Unity app using AltUnity Tester that run in the Unity Editor.  However, I'm having issues executing the same Python scripts in IOS Simulator.  I'm able to establish a connection to the 13000 server, but I get errors when trying to interact with elements.

Here is the editor code:

```
import os
import unittest
import time
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy
#from altunityrunner import AltrunUnityDriver
#from altunityrunner import By
from altunityrunner import *


class SimulatorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    altdriver = None


    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print("here we go!")
        cls.altdriver = AltUnityDriver(None, 'ios','127.0.0.1',13000,log_flag = True)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("we're done!")
        cls.altdriver.stop()
        

    def test_play(cls):
        time.sleep(10)
        cls.altdriver.find_object(By.NAME,"AnimatedPlayButton").tap()

        print("Done")

        cls.altdriver.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimulatorTest)
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

Here is the IOS Simulator code:

```
import os
import unittest
import time
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy
#from altunityrunner import AltrunUnityDriver
#from altunityrunner import By
from altunityrunner import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class SimulatorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    altdriver = None
    platform = "ios"

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.desired_caps = {}
        cls.desired_caps['platformName'] = 'iOS'
        cls.desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'iPhone 11'
        cls.desired_caps['automationName'] = 'XCUITest'
        cls.desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '13.4'
        app = os.path.abspath('/Users/domenicsorace/Desktop/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphonesimulator/twodotsdev.app')
        cls.desired_caps['app'] = app
        cls.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', cls.desired_caps)
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(cls.driver, 5)
        # close the iOS pop up
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((MobileBy.ID, "Allow")))
        cls.driver.switch_to.context('NATIVE_APP')
        cls.driver.find_element_by_id("Allow").click()
        cls.altdriver = AltUnityDriver(None, 'ios','192.168.0.3',13000,log_flag = True)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.altdriver.stop()
        

    def test_play(cls):
        cls.altdriver.find_object(By.NAME,"AnimatedPlayButton").tap()
        print("Done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimulatorTest)
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

Errors:

```
2020-09-18 15:41:34.730 | DEBUG    | altunityrunner.commands.base_command:recvall:46 - Received data was: error:unknownError;System.Exception: Expected / or // instead of None
  at Assets.AltUnityTester.AltUnityServer.AltUnityBaseClassFindObjectsCommand.SetCondition (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] list) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at Assets.AltUnityTester.AltUnityServer.AltUnityBaseClassFindObjectsCommand.ProcessPath (System.String path) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at Assets.AltUnityTester.AltUnityServer.Commands.AltUnityFindObjectCommand.Execute () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at AltUnityCommand+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<SendResponse>b__0 () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at AltResponseQueue.Cycle () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
2020-09-18 15:41:34.730 | DEBUG    | altunityrunner.commands.command_returning_alt_elements:get_alt_element:16 - error:unknownError;System.Exception: Expected / or // instead of None
  at Assets.AltUnityTester.AltUnityServer.AltUnityBaseClassFindObjectsCommand.SetCondition (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] list) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at Assets.AltUnityTester.AltUnityServer.AltUnityBaseClassFindObjectsCommand.ProcessPath (System.String path) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at Assets.AltUnityTester.AltUnityServer.Commands.AltUnityFindObjectCommand.Execute () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at AltUnityCommand+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<SendResponse>b__0 () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
  at AltResponseQueue.Cycle () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment this line:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

`By` definition from altunityrunner is overridden by line above.